# How to use a string function result in WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySql, how to use a string function result in WHERE IN clause?

eg:-

`select * from product p left join catalog c on c.catalogid in ((TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM (REPLACE(p.catalog_ids,',,',',')))));`

Here **p.catalogs_ids=',36,,37,,38,';**

But above query results in

```
select * from product p left join catalog c on c.catalogid in ('36,37,38');
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: write select which includes where part statement inside of function

Comment: You can't use a string directly as values for `IN (...)`. You can use FIND_IN_SET in this case but it will probably not use an index for the join.

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but normalizing the database schema by creating a join table between catalog ids and products would be the proper solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use IN on a string. Do a string comparison instead using like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product p 
  LEFT JOIN catalog c 
    ON ',' + p.catalog_ids + ',' LIKE  '%,' + c.catalogid + ',%'
```

It's a little convoluted with the extra commas but this is to ensure the match is on whole numbers and not part of a number. You didn't say what type catalogid is so you may need to cast it like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product p 
  LEFT JOIN catalog c 
    ON ',' + p.catalog_ids + ',' LIKE  '%,' + CAST(c.catalogid AS CHAR) + ',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you maybe looking for this

```
select * from product p 
left join catalog c on c.catalogid in (',36,',',37,',',38,');
```